# How to merge with smallest Euclidean distance?

Tags: python, pandas, data

Given a main `left` dataset, how can I merge with `right` dataset with smallest Euclidean distance (`d = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)`) on specified columns?

Details:

- if both of `key1` and `key2` from `left` exist in `right`, merge with row that matches `key1` and `key2`, and has smallest value from `sqrt((aux1r - aux1l)^2 + (aux2r - aux2l)^2)`
- if both of `key1` and `key2` are not `NaN` and either of `key1` and `key2` from `left` does not exist in `right`, merge with row that has smallest value from `sqrt((aux1r - aux1l)^2 + (aux2r - aux2l)^2)`
- if one of `key1` or `key2` from left is `NaN`, merge with row from right that matches the non-`NaN` `key1` or `key2`, and has smallest value from `sqrt((aux1r - aux1l)^2 + (aux2r - aux2l)^2)`
- if both of `key1` and `key2` from left is `NaN`, merge with row from right that has smallest value from `sqrt((aux1r - aux1l)^2 + (aux2r - aux2l)^2)`

Example of input dataframes, and wanted dataframe after merge:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

left = pd.DataFrame([
    #  "key1"      "key2"        "aux1l" "aux2l" "left1"        "left2"
    [np.nan,       np.nan,       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[0]
    ["key1",       np.nan,       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[1]
    [np.nan,       "key2",       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[2]
    ["key1",       "key2",       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[3]
    ["key1unique", "key2unique", 1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[4]
    ["key1repeat", "key2repeat", 1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[5]
    ["key1repeat", "key2repeat", 1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant"],  # left[6]
], columns=["key1", "key2", "aux1l", "aux2l", "left1", "left2"])

right = pd.DataFrame([
    # "key1"       "key2"        "aux1r"  "aux2r"  "right1"       "right2"
    [np.nan,       "key2",       0.99,    0.97,    "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1",       "key2",       0.99,    0.96,    "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1repeat", "key2repeat", 1.85,    1.56,    "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1repeat", "key2repeat", 0.99,    0.99,    "unimportant", "unimportant"],
], columns=["key1", "key2", "aux1r", "aux2r", "right1", "right2"])

# what to do here?
# left.merge(right) discards left with no matches (left[4] discarded, but want to fill with closest match with aux1l/aux2l with aux1r/aux2r)

# it does not matter if aux1r and aux2r is included
wanted = pd.DataFrame([
    # "key1"       "key2"        "auxl1"  "aux2l" "left1"       "left2"        "right1"       "right2"
    [np.nan,       np.nan,       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1",       np.nan,       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    [np.nan,       "key2",       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1",       "key2",       1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1unique", "key2unique", 1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1repeat", "key2repeat", 1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
    ["key1repeat", "key2repeat", 1.00,   1.00,   "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant", "unimportant"],
], columns=["key1", "key2", "aux1l", "aux2l", "left1", "left2", "right1", "right2"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the requirements

A wanted row from the right dataframe is a row that

1. has the least amount of unmatched keys
2. has the minimum euclidean distance

```py
def merge_left_and_right(left, right):
    # save original input from modification
    left = left.copy()
    right = right.copy()
    
    # numerate rows in the right dataframe
    right['row_num'] = range(len(right))

    # find the best matchings for left dataframe
    left['row_num'] = [
        find_the_best_matching(right,
                               key1=row['key1'],
                               key2=row['key2'],
                               aux1l=row['aux1l'],
                               aux2l=row['aux2l'])
        for index, row in left.iterrows()
    ]
    
    # merge dataframe by row number
    right = right.drop(['key1', 'key2'], axis=1)
    merged = left.merge(right, on='row_num', how='left')
    merged = merged.drop('row_num', axis=1)
    
    return merged

def find_the_best_matching(right, key1, key2, aux1l, aux2l):
    right = right.copy()

    # keys match only when they aren't NaN and equal ("np.nan != np.nan" is True)
    right['unmatched_key_count'] = 0
    right['unmatched_key_count'] += (right['key1'] != key1).astype(int)
    right['unmatched_key_count'] += (right['key2'] != key2).astype(int)

    right['euclidean_distance'] = np.sqrt((right['aux1r'] - aux1l) ** 2 + (right['aux2r'] - aux2l) ** 2)
    
    # Sort by unmatched amount, then by distance. The first row will be best
    return right.sort_values(['unmatched_key_count', 'euclidean_distance']).iloc[0]['row_num']
```

[image]